# Getting Error mochawesome-merge error: unknown option: --reportDir

Tags: cypress, mochawesome

On merging JSON reports through cmd, I am getting error in report.json(converted one)

```
error: unknown option: --reportDir
```

**Used below command**

```
run mochawesome-merge --reportDir cypress\reports\mochawesome-report  > cypress\reports\mocha\report.json
```

Used:
os: Windows

```
"devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^4.2.0",
    "cypress-multi-reporters": "^1.2.4",
    "mocha": "^7.1.1",
    "mochawesome": "^5.0.0",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^3.0.0",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^4.1.0"
  },

  "reporter": "mochawesome",
  "reporterOptions":{
      "reportDir": "cypress/reports/mochawesome-report",    
      "reportFilename": "CustomeMocaReport",
      "quiet": true,
      "overwrite": false,
      "html": false,
      "json": true  

  },
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your first command `run` was not recognized so I suggest you to use `npx` instead

```
npx mochawesome-merge --reportDir cypress\reports\mochawesome-report  > cypress\reports\mocha\report.json
```

if it will not work check the path, I think you have a problem there with slash because in your `cypress.json` you use normal slash `/` but in command backslash `\` !